# Getting back to Parent navigation container from Child Navigation container

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

My Whole Navigation Life Cycle (explanation) :

App.js:
Route(stack Screen): Splashscreen  , Login Screen , Register Screen ,

optpscreen (componenet =  (child)

Drawernavigation.js:

Nav(Drawer screens): homescreen , logout screen ( componenet = loginscreen ( defined at Route navigation conatiner for reset purpose from logout )

Problem Facing : Cant navigate from Nav (logout) to Route (login screen) --- Want a reset

Code :-

App.js

```
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();


export function Route(){
  return(<>
  <NavigationContainer independent={true}>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName='SplashScreen' screenOptions={{headerStyle:{
        backgroundColor:'#e6e6e6'
      }}}>

        
        {/* drawerScreen */}
        <Stack.Screen name="Nav" options={{ headerShown: false }} component={Nav} />
        
        {/* Navigation screens */}
        <Stack.Screen  options={{headerShown: false}}  name="SplashScreen" component={SplashScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen options={{headerShown: false}} name="LoginScreen" component={LoginScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen options={{title:''}} name="Otpscreen" component={Otpscreen} />
        <Stack.Screen options={{title:''}} name="Registerscreen" component={Registerscreen} />



      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  </>)
}


function App(){
  
  return(<>
<Route />
  </>)
}

export default App;
```

DrawerNvigation.js

```
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();



const CustomDrawer = (props) => {
    return (<>
    
       <View>
       <View>
        <Image style={styles.Imagecss} source={require('../../assets/bq1.jpg')} />
       </View>
       <Text style={styles.BanquetNameCss}>Centeral Venue</Text>
       </View>
        <Text></Text>
        <DrawerItemList {...props} />
    
    </>)
}

return(
<>
    <StatusBar barStyle="dark" />
   
   
    <NavigationContainer independent={true}>

        <Drawer.Navigator drawerContent={(props)=><CustomDrawer {...props}/>} initialRouteName="Inquiries">

    <Drawer.Screen name="Inquiries" component={Mainscreen} 
        options={{
        drawerLabel:"Home"  ,
        drawerIcon: ({size}) => ( 
        <Icon name="home"  
        size={size} 
        color='black'
        /> ),
        }} />


<Drawer.Screen name="Sign Out" component={LoginScreen} 
        options={{
            drawerLabel:"Sign Out",
            drawerIcon: ({size}) => (
       
            <Icon name="sign-out"
        size={size}
        color='black'
        /> ) }}


> listeners={({navigation})=>{
> navigation.replace(<Route/>)
        }}

        />
   
        </Drawer.Navigator>
    
        </NavigationContainer>
    </>)
}
```

> Cant navigate from child to parent Can anyone help me to get this navigation life cycle working :)

I tried using this logic

```
<Drawer.Screen name="Sign Out" component={LoginScreen}
```

my login.js code :

```
function LoginScreen({navigation}){

    function preshandler(){
 navigation.navigate('Registerscreen');
    }
```

But it shows erorr of pay load like this one :
[Erorr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQ8OG.png)

Comment: can you give me full code link ?

Answer (score 1):

According to [React Navigation Official Document](https://dev.atal.com.hk/dl/ATALMobileAccess.apk), `independent` props to `true` in your navigators indicates **disconnects any parent navigators**.

So, this should be the main reason you cannot navigation back to the parent stack navigator.

Or you have any reason for that?